# How to declare a JS mixin for vue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm writting a vue project with typescript and I want to use a mixin from thrid-part library which write by javascript, how to write a `.d.ts` to make ts can find function define in the mixin?

I tried this way and it not working:

```
// common.d.ts
declare module 'thrid-part-lib' {
    import { VueClass } from 'vue-class-component/lib/declarations';

    export interface SomeMixin<T> extends VueClass<T> {
        refresh(): Promise<void>;
    }
}
```

```
// index.ts
import { Component, Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { SomeMixin } from 'thrid-part-lib';

@Component
export default class Index extends Mixins(SomeMixin) {
    public foo() {
        this.refresh(); // 'refresh' is not define.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can augment a third party mixin with creating a file like `vuelidate-error-extractor.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'vuelidate-error-extractor' {
   import { ValidationRule } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';

   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/class-name-casing
   export class singleErrorExtractorMixin extends Vue {
      readonly events: any;

      readonly name: string;

      readonly isValid: boolean;

      readonly hasErrors: boolean;

      readonly preferredValidator: ValidationRule;
   }
}
```

This augments [this JS file](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vuelidate-error-extractor/blob/9590f9b8c7ba28338276a68a2545c5e798666113/src/single-error-extractor-mixin.js), but in an incomplete manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in ["Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins).

Put this in a `.d.ts` file in your project to add a `refresh()` mixin method to components:

```
// 1. Make sure to import 'vue' before declaring augmented types
import Vue from 'vue'

// 2. Specify a file with the types you want to augment
//    Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    refresh():  void;
  }
}
```

Comment: But I only want to use `refreh` in the component which be mixed, this way will pollute the whole Vue instance.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I don't know about declaration files for single components.